# How to create an anchor link inside a single page in Balsamiq?

Tags: balsamiq

I have a wireframe in `Balsamiq`.
I know how to link to another screen.

I would like to click a button and open a popup on the same screen. Is it possible with `Balsamiq`?

Comment: Same question. Please update your question if you find the answer.

Comment: Don't worry, Layke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not something you can achieve in our little tool which has low interactivity on purpose, as detailed here: https://blogs.balsamiq.com/ux/2011/06/17/why-we-arent-doing-interaction/

The Linking feature is indeed the best way to achieve this result in Balsamiq Mockups.

Please let us know if you need anything else, we're here to help! (support@balsamiq.com)

-Virgin from Balsamiq